# Can't install python javabridge

Tags: java, pip, jvm

When I run the command `pip install javabridge` I'm getting the following error:

`Could not find Java JRE compatible with x86_64 architecture
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/qk/qv11w6l52rn983d99j5zzrr40000gn/T/pip-build-pen46dwr/javabridge/setup.py", line 396, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext_modules(),
      File "/private/var/folders/qk/qv11w6l52rn983d99j5zzrr40000gn/T/pip-build-pen46dwr/javabridge/setup.py", line 89, in ext_modules
        raise Exception("JVM not found")
    Exception: JVM not found`

Answer (score 0):

Javabridge requires Python 2.6+, NumPy, the Java Development Kit (JDK), and a C compiler: see https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/blob/master/docs/installation.rst for the installation instructions.